# When using the @ManyToOne and @OneToMany annotations, a stackoverflow exception is thrown

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data

It seems like all the anotations for Hibernate are above variables in classes, but for what day I can't get rid of stackoverflow. I also use spring-data.

Here's what the exception is:

```
Root Cause

java.lang.StackOverflowError
    java.base/java.lang.Integer.toString(Integer.java:1196)
    java.base/java.lang.StringConcatHelper.stringOf(StringConcatHelper.java:453)
    com.example.application.model.Ticket.toString(Ticket.java:210)
    java.base/java.lang.StringConcatHelper.stringOf(StringConcatHelper.java:453)
    com.example.application.model.Material.toString(Material.java:166)
    java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:4215)
    java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:173)
    java.base/java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:457)
    org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:622)
    java.base/java.lang.StringConcatHelper.stringOf(StringConcatHelper.java:453)
    com.example.application.model.Ticket.toString(Ticket.java:210)
    java.base/java.lang.StringConcatHelper.stringOf(StringConcatHelper.java:453)
    com.example.application.model.Material.toString(Material.java:166)
    java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:4215)
    java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:173)
    java.base/java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:457)
    org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:622)
    java.base/java.lang.StringConcatHelper.stringOf(StringConcatHelper.java:453)
    com.example.application.model.Ticket.toString(Ticket.java:210)
    java.base/java.lang.StringConcatHelper.stringOf(StringConcatHelper.java:453)
    com.example.application.model.Material.toString(Material.java:166)
    java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:4215)
    java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:173)
    java.base/java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:457)
    org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:622)
    java.base/java.lang.StringConcatHelper.stringOf(StringConcatHelper.java:453)
    com.example.application.model.Ticket.toString(Ticket.java:210)
    java.base/java.lang.StringConcatHelper.stringOf(StringConcatHelper.java:453)
    com.example.application.model.Material.toString(Material.java:166)
    java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:4215)
    java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:173)
    java.base/java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:457)
    org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:622)
    java.base/java.lang.StringConcatHelper.stringOf(StringConcatHelper.java:453)
    com.example.application.model.Ticket.toString(Ticket.java:210)
    java.base/java.lang.StringConcatHelper.stringOf(StringConcatHelper.java:453)
    com.example.application.model.Material.toString(Material.java:166)
    java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:4215)
    java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:173)
    java.base/java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:457)
    org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:622)
    java.base/java.lang.StringConcatHelper.stringOf(StringConcatHelper.java:453)
    com.example.application.model.Ticket.toString(Ticket.java:210)
    java.base/java.lang.StringConcatHelper.stringOf(StringConcatHelper.java:453)
    com.example.application.model.Material.toString(Material.java:166)
    java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:4215)
    java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:173)
    java.base/java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:457)
    org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:622)
    java.base/java.lang.StringConcatHelper.stringOf(StringConcatHelper.java:453)
    com.example.application.model.Ticket.toString(Ticket.java:210)
    java.base/java.lang.StringConcatHelper.stringOf(StringConcatHelper.java:453)
    com.example.application.model.Material.toString(Material.java:166)
    java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:4215)
    java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:173)
    java.base/java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:457)
    org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:622)
    java.base/java.lang.StringConcatHelper.stringOf(StringConcatHelper.java:453)
    com.example.application.model.Ticket.toString(Ticket.java:210)
    java.base/java.lang.StringConcatHelper.stringOf(StringConcatHelper.java:453)
    com.example.application.model.Material.toString(Material.java:166)
    java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:4215)
    java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:173)
    java.base/java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:457)
    org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:622)
    java.base/java.lang.StringConcatHelper.stringOf(StringConcatHelper.java:453)
    com.example.application.model.Ticket.toString(Ticket.java:210)
    java.base/java.lang.StringConcatHelper.stringOf(StringConcatHelper.java:453)
    com.example.application.model.Material.toString(Material.java:166)
    java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:4215)
    java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:173)
    java.base/java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:457)
    org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:622)
    java.base/java.lang.StringConcatHelper.stringOf(StringConcatHelper.java:453)
    com.example.application.model.Ticket.toString(Ticket.java:210)
    java.base/java.lang.StringConcatHelper.stringOf(StringConcatHelper.java:453)
    com.example.application.model.Material.toString(Material.java:166)
    java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:4215)
    java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:173)
    java.base/java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:457)
    org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:622)
    java.base/java.lang.StringConcatHelper.stringOf(StringConcatHelper.java:453)
    com.example.application.model.Ticket.toString(Ticket.java:210)
    java.base/java.lang.StringConcatHelper.stringOf(StringConcatHelper.java:453)
    com.example.application.model.Material.toString(Material.java:166)
    java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:4215)
    java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:173)
    java.base/java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:457)
    org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:622)
    java.base/java.lang.StringConcatHelper.stringOf(StringConcatHelper.java:453)
    com.example.application.model.Ticket.toString(Ticket.java:210)
    java.base/java.lang.StringConcatHelper.stringOf(StringConcatHelper.java:453)
    com.example.application.model.Material.toString(Material.java:166)
    java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:4215)
    java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:173)
    java.base/java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:457)
    org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:622)
    java.base/java.lang.StringConcatHelper.stringOf(StringConcatHelper.java:453)
    com.example.application.model.Ticket.toString(Ticket.java:210)
    java.base/java.lang.StringConcatHelper.stringOf(StringConcatHelper.java:453)
    com.example.application.model.Material.toString(Material.java:166)
    java.base/java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:4215)
    java.base/java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:173)
    java.base/java.util.AbstractCollection.toString(AbstractCollection.java:457)
    org.hibernate.collection.internal.PersistentBag.toString(PersistentBag.java:622)
    java.base/java.lang.StringConcatHelper.stringOf(StringConcatHelper.java:453)
    com.example.application.model.Ticket.toString(Ticket.java:210)
    java.base/java.lang.StringConcatHelper.stringOf(StringConcatHelper.java:453)
    com.example.application.model.Material.toString(Material.java:166)
```

I see this in debugging:

[image]

class Ticket

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "tickets")
public class Ticket extends AbstractNamedEntity implements HasId {

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "ticket")
    @OrderBy("name DESC")
    @BatchSize(size = 100)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @JsonIgnore
    private List<Material> materials;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", nullable = false)
    @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
    @BatchSize(size = 50)
    @JsonIgnore
    private User user;
}
```

class Material

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "materials")
public class Material extends AbstractNamedEntity implements HasId {

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "ticket_id")
  @OnDelete(action = OnDeleteAction.CASCADE)
  @JsonIgnore
  private Ticket ticket;
}
```

I have tried such a request:

```
  @Transactional(readOnly = true)
  public interface CrudTicketRepository extends JpaRepository<Ticket, Integer> {
     
      @EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"materials"}, type = EntityGraph.EntityGraphType.LOAD)
      @Query("SELECT t FROM Ticket t WHERE t.id=:id")                                      
      Ticket getWithMaterial(@Param("id") int id);
}
```

Then this:

```
@Query("SELECT t FROM Ticket t JOIN FETCH Material m WHERE t.id=:id AND m.ticket.id=:id")
Ticket findById(@Param("id") int id);
```

I also tried FetchType.EAGER and it doesn't work to change anything there ((( Help.

Comment: Is it only happening for the `toString`? If so, the easiest solution may be to override `Material`'s `toString` and make sure that it doesn't print `Ticket`. The stack overflow comes from the fact that the ticket is printing its materiais that is printing the ticket and so on ad infinitum.

Comment: If you are using Lombok annotation ToString you can add @ToString.Exclude to the fields you want to exclude. Similar to JsonIgnore you are using already.

Comment: `Ticket.toString()` calls `Material.toString()` calls `Ticket.toString()` calls ...

Comment: I didn't think toString was overflowing the stack. After all, even after I repaired it, when I debug, there is still recursion in the objects, although the stack does not overflow, why? @AnthonyAccioly

Comment: The JPA provider (e.g., Hibernate) is doing the heavy work for you - it knows how to deal with bidirectional associations and avoid infinite recursion. Once the objects are in memory, you can think of associations as references: Having object `A` pointing to `B` and object `B` pointing to `A` is perfectly normal. As long as you don't try to follow the path `a.b.a.b.[...]` (like `toString` was doing in your example), everything works fine.

Answer (score 0):

try : `@ToString.Exclude` on your `@OneToMany` property